# Error with CLR when I deploy VS2022 app in Windows 7/10 8007000e

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, desktop-application

I'm migrating my desktop application from Visual Studio 2008 to 2022 in Windows 7/10, using .NET Framework 3.5. When I deployed the new EXE, the "**Error CLR: 8007000e**" showed up; even the old EXE started to show the same error, and I could not use the program any more.
I tried updating Windows, installing different patches, changing targets in the application, giving administrator privileges, and taking the computer out of the domain, and nothing worked.
Please help.

[image: CLR Error]

Comment: You should also migrate to .Net 4.8 and drop support for Windows 7, because those older platforms are no longer supported to the point critical security bugs from the last few years remain **unpatched.**

Comment: Hi Joel, In fact, I tried with .NET 4.5 and got the same error. The only way to manage this is to charge a restoration point in Windows and keep using the old EXE.

Comment: Does this happen when running in the debugger, too?

Comment: Hi PMF, the error occurs only on the user's computers; everything works perfectly on my machine (debugging mode or running node) and some others. A curious fact is that in 15 running tests, in 3 the program runs fine, and in 17 it does not run and shows the error message.